# Django Python how to implement my custom birth date function in views?

Tags: python, django

I write this python function for calculate age.

```
def age(birthdate):
    today = date.today()
    age = today.year - birthdate.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (birthdate.month, birthdate.day))
    return age
```

**result:**

```
>>> print(age(date(1980, 1, 1)))
42
```

here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class CalculateAge(models.Model):
      age = models.IntegerField(max_length=100)
      date_of_birth = models.DateField()
```

user only pick the date of birth and I want age will be automatically calculate when submitting forms.

**views.py**

```
def CalculateAge(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       patient_from = AddPatientFrom(request.POST or None)
       if patient_from.is_valid(): 
          patient_from.save()
```

how to implement this age function in my views.py and models.py?

I tried this in my views.py but didn't work.

```
if patient_from.is_valid(): 
      pick_date = request.POST['date_of_birth']
      find_age = age(date(pick_date))
      print(find_age)
```

getting this error:

`TypeError at /add-patient/ an integer is required (got type str)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should work with the [**`.cleaned_data`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data) of the form: this will contain the data as `date` object:

```
if patient_from.is_valid(): 
      pick_date = form.cleaned_data['date_of_birth']
      find_age = age(age_y)
      print(find_age)
```

Comment: now getting this error `an integer is required (got type datetime.date)`

Comment: @boyenec: can you edit the question will the full traceback?

Comment: what do you mean by  full traceback?

Comment: @boyenec: nvm, you should remove the `date(...)` from `age(date(...))`, so `age(age_y)`.

Comment: @boyenec: because `date(...)` expects at least three integers. `form.cleaned_data['date_of_birth']` has a `date`, hence the two do not work well together.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240657/discussion-between-boyenec-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: is there any way to find age like this 24 year 56days. which also calculate year and days together?